# Pearsonr with two arrays that have nan values

Tags: python, pearson-correlation

I have two arrays with values that correspond to dates in the year. I am trying to find the correlation coefficient between array a and b for the year when both arrays have values. Many of values are nan for both arrays.

```py
from scipy import stats 
import numpy as np   

dates = np.array([2/3, 2/4, 2/5, 2/8, 2/9, 2/10, 2/11])

a = np.array([-9999., 4, 6, 7, -9999., 8, -9999.])
b = np.array([3, -9999., 5, 8, -9999., 7, 9])

a[a==-9999] = np.nan
b[b==-9999] = np.nan

r,p= stats.mstats.pearsonr(a,b)
```

In this case, only the 2nd, 3rd, and 5th indices could be used for this calculation because there are non nan values for both arrays. I've figured out how to remove the nans, but when I do it, messes up the indexing. So it's not useful for me.

Comment: I don't get something here, is the dates array supposed to be the division between two numbers? How do you diffrentiate 2/4 from 1/2 which are equal in that case (for example). Also, how do you have `nan` in python? That's not a valid code. (did you mean "None")? This code won't run at all as is

Comment: I just included the dates array for clarity. I'm not actually using the date array when I calculate the correlation coefficient. I set the -9999 values in both the a and b array using numpy.nan. You can have nan values in python.

Comment: You should include the minimum code possible to recreate your error on our end, otherwise we can't run the code to reproduce your errors (without a lot of extra work and guessing) and we can't really help you

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. It should run now.

Answer (score 2):

I just combined the two arrays into a single array:

```
c = np.vstack([a,b])
>>> array([[nan,  4.,  6.,  7., nan,  8., nan],
           [ 3., nan,  5.,  8., nan,  7.,  9.]])
```

Delete any columns that contain any NaN

```
d = c[:,~np.any(np.isnan(c), axis=0)]
>>> array([[6., 7., 8.],
           [5., 8., 7.]])
```

Then compute correlation using scipy:

```
r,p= stats.mstats.pearsonr(d[0],d[1])
>>> 0.6546536707079772 0.54562894834299
```

or numpy:

```
np.correlate(d[0],d[1])
>>> 0.654653670707977
```